# How do I create WooCommerce Custom Product Sorting style?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce

I want to change the default sorting style given in WooCommerce plugin. 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtjZ2.png)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have already copy the WooCommerce template `woocommerce/templates` to your theme. You can find the WooCommerce structure [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Once you have the WooCommerce template under your theme, looking for `woocommerce/loop/orderby.php`, this is where you can custom the product order. To change different order list, here is the code snippet to demonstrate how to do that:

```
//your-theme/woocommerce/loop/orderby.php
<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
  <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
    <?php
      $catalog_orderby = apply_filters('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
        'title'   => __('Alphabetically', 'woocommerce'),
        'date'    => __('Most Recent', 'woocommerce'),
        'price'   => __('Price Asc', 'woocommerce'),
        'price-desc'  => __('Price Desc', 'woocommerce')
      ));
    ?>
    <?php foreach ( $catalog_orderby as $id => $name ) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php selected( $orderby, $id ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $name ); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

You can add or remove any options from the $catalog_orderby above.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **'price-asc**'   => __('Price Asc', 'woocommerce'),
    'price-desc'  => __('Price Desc', 'woocommerce')
  ));
```

Must changed to this now work*

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue